# can someone say is it possible to export event to outlook from rails application using icalendar gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, outlook, icalendar

can someone say is it possible to export event to outlook from rails application using icalendar gem by adding addition fields?

if not please suggest me some way to do that

Thanks,
Dhanabal

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about rails and gem, but here is what the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757?wa=wsignin1.0) article says:

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.